# access permuted value with next_permutation

Tags: c++

How do I use a permuted number outside while loop like to make comparisons.. Because I have checked, vector outside while is same as defined earlier.

```
void display(vector<int> vec){
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size();i++){
        cout<<vec[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
  vector <int> vec;
  vec.push_back(3);
  vec.push_back(2);
  vec.push_back(1);
  vec.push_back(4);
  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  while (next_permutation( vec.begin(), vec.end() )){
  display(vec);
  cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: [Looks fine to me.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3qbJl6$2)

Comment: I don't think it calculates all permutations.

Comment: Hmm, made a complete pgm out of your example, and it prints 24 permutations as it should

Comment: May be I have my compiler issues.

Comment: Got the issue...............thanks fellas

Comment: @NPE: I'll see your Meta link and raise you a http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate

Comment: @cHao: I won't debate the rights and wrongs. However, I will state that I find the implication offensive, especially given that I have attempted to answer the question (unlike everyone else bar a single other person).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following **complete program** works fine both with Visual C++ and with g++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template< class Item >
wostream& operator<<( wostream& stream, vector<Item> const& v )
{
    stream << "[";
    for( auto p = v.begin(); p != v.end();  ++p )
    {
        if( p != v.begin() ) { wcout << ", "; }
        wcout << *p;
    }
    stream << "]";
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    int const   data[]  = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    vector <int> vec( begin( data ), end( data ) ); 
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    do
    {
        wcout << vec << endl; 
    } while (next_permutation( vec.begin(), vec.end() ) );
}
```

The main code is identical to your code (it was copied and pasted, and just edited a teeny tiny little bit to add the data).

So, given that the code works, what exactly is the problem?

---

**EDIT**: the OP has now updated the question with different code, a `while` loop instead of a `do` loop, and the order of the calls to `next_permutation` and `display` changed so that it fails to display the original permutation.

The new code given,

```
void display(vector<int> vec){
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size();i++){
        cout<<vec[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
  vector <int> vec;
  vec.push_back(3);
  vec.push_back(2);
  vec.push_back(1);
  vec.push_back(4);
  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  while (next_permutation( vec.begin(), vec.end() )){
  display(vec);
  cout<<endl;
}
```

does not compile even after adding the requisite headers and a `using namespace std;`.

While this is only due to a missing right brace, it would have been avoided by *copying and pasting* the code from a working version.

That is also much less work to do. :-)

Comment: I got my issue. Just one more thing how do I access the permuted number. In case I need to use it for some purpose.

Comment: Oh, you want to interpret it as a sequence of decimal digits? well, i would just code up a loop to compute the corresponding numerical value (multiplying each digit by a power of 10, see also "Horner's rule"). using the standard library you could transform the digits into ASCII characters, append them one at a time to a `string`, and then use the library facility of your choice to convert that to number, but really it's faster to just code up the loop. :-)

Comment: I am a bit new in c++. Can you please post the code here. Every thing you mentioned seems unfathomable to me. :)

Comment: @HardCode wouldn't that deprive you of any opportunity _and_ incentive to learn?